# How to unsubscribe from the rxJava request

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have the following class, I want to return Subscription object or something else so I can cancel the request from where I have referenced subscribe() method , but subscribe(observer) returns void!
How can I do that?

```
public abstract class MainPresenter<T> {
protected <T> Disposable subscribe(Observable<T> observable, Observer<T> observer) {
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);

}
```

[*New Update*]
I used this way temporary, I am waiting for better solutions:

```
    protected <T> DisposableMaybeObserver subscribe(final Maybe<T> observable,
                                                final Observer<T> observer) {
    return observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableMaybeObserver<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(T t) {
                    observer.onNext(t);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    observer.onError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            });
}
```

[*New Update 2*]
[![Screenshot][https://i.stack.imgur.com/mioth.jpg]]

[*New Update 3*]
[[image: Screenshot2]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XnLB.jpg)

Comment: Use a `DisposableObserver` and simply return its instance.

Comment: @akarnokd Can you provide an example?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should maybe use use `subscribeWith` :

```
private Disposable mDisposable;

public abstract class MainPresenter<T> {
protected Disposable subscribe(Observable<T> observable, DisposableObserver<T> observer) {
mDisposable = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(observer);

return mDisposable;

}
```

Then when you need :

```
if (mDisposable != null && !mDisposable.isDisposed()) {
    mDisposable.dispose();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: observable from "io.reactivex.Observer" package haven't method subscribeOn()

Comment: Have you try my proposal ?

Comment: Yes,but it says subscribeOn is not defined.  These are my import packages:
import io.reactivex.Maybe;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.observers.DisposableMaybeObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

Comment: Verify that your Observable import is a io.reactivex and not a java.util for exemple.

Comment: It is import io.reactivex.Observer;

Comment: Look for Observable not Observer :) You use a Observer instead of Observable , look my code .

Comment: It can't resolve. Please see the screenshot in my update! I don't know why

Comment: Nope still problem, the problem is with subscribeOn method which still still not resolved., not the return Type.

Comment: Weird , have you try to remove your import and re-import ?  io.reactivex.Observable

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache even. Please see the new screenshot update2.

Comment: Can i see your import please  and your build.gradle file ?

Comment: Thank you very much Cochi. It was my mistake in import, it changed to java.database.Observer itself and I didn't notice. I resolve this as the answer.

Comment: However I want to reference an interface to subscribe method in parent class as the second parameter, because DisposableObserver itself is a class I can't implement it. I need an interface to implement. Have anther class which extends ```MainPresenter``` and should implements an interface so I can set subscribe method in Parent. How can I achieve it?
I want to do something like this in the child class:
subscribe(getMoreCakeObserver(cat, skip, limit, description), this);
In which 'this' resolves to the interface I should implement. Which interface should I use do you think?

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)  
i 'm not sur to understand your new issue, but you should open a new post for this issue with relevants informations, like that me or someone could help you easier.